# Want my scroll bar always at the bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

My Html Div In Which Chat is in While Loop. So I want My Scroll Always at Bottom But Its Not Working For Me. I'd like some help with a script compatible to the below scripts, any one of them.

```
<div class="panel-body">
```

CSS Code

```
.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

I used two different scripts:

1)

```
$('.panel-body').scrollTop($('.panel-body')[0].scrollHeight);
```

2)

```
var myDiv = document.getElementByClassName(".panel-body");
myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Pro posting tip: when asking for help, see how people can **help you do the work**. Questions of the form "please provide a script" are asking other people to do your work for you, and such questions get closed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily using javascript...

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

See the [sample code here...](http://codepen.io/apmeena/pen/vKZyAj)

Comment: its not working for me where should i use this one on same page at the top in .<script> tag or in .js file ?

Comment: sorry but that code is only working for body tag and not for div class look at my code i have div class=panel-body

Comment: var div = document.getElemetById("#idOfDiv"); window.scrollTo(0,document.div.scrollHeight);  Try this...